# Visual c++ - autocorrect

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cout << "Can't find cout, did you mean std::cout?";
    return 0;
}
```

If this were java code eclipse/intellij would have told me that it couldn't find `cout` and it would give me a list of possible solutions to this error, for example `std::cout`

I never saw something similar in c++ and I somehow miss this feature. It was very useful for importing libraries in java because you just had to type something like `cout` and the IDE would recommend you to `#include <iostream>` without jumping to the top of your file.

Does something similar exists in visual c++? (or other IDE's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about IDEs, but `clang` will do that:

```
$ clang++ test.C 
test.C:5:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'cout'; did you mean 'std::cout'?
    cout << "Can't find cout, did you mean std::cout?";
    ^~~~
    std::cout
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:63:18: note: 'std::cout' declared here
  extern ostream cout;          ///< Linked to standard output
                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Recent GCC versions will do it too:

```
$ g++ test.C 
test.C: In function ‘int main()’:
test.C:5:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
test.C:5:5: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from test.C:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7.1/iostream:62:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
```

Comment: GCC does something like this as well.

Comment: @chris - which version?  I tried Apple's llvm-gcc 4.2 and GCC 4.4.4 on a linux machine and it didn't.

Comment: Found it on a 4.7 install.  Editing answer.

Comment: Okay that is nice, but then it shouldn't be a problem to implement this feature in an IDE, right? Something like if you press `ctrl+1` over an error , you get a list of possible solutions to fix this problem. I guess I just have to wait.

Comment: @Maik Klein, I'm sure you're right.  I don't use an IDE normally, so I'm just not up to date on that front.  I'm sure Xcode does it.